# Is it possible to supply the jQuery Validation plugin with a rules object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I took the rules that I'd been using to validate my form and broke them out into a JSON object, hoping to use the same set of rules for client/server validation.

So, where I had:

```
$(document.getElementById('new_listing_form')).validate({
    rules: {
        apt: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

I'm attempting to use:

```
var rules_obj = {
    apt: {
        required: true
    }
};
$(document.getElementById('new_listing_form')).validate({
    rules: rules_obj 
});
```

... and the form is not being validated.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it's perfectly fine... and one thing,

```
$('#new_listing_form').validate({
```

is same thing as yours... `#` means it's a `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: Thanks, but there's a performance gain when using the native DOM method. http://jsperf.com/vs-document-getelementbyid

Comment: I had the properties in my JSON object wrapped in double-quotes and they were being treated as strings. Doh!